# No such module 'AWSCore'

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]

Im new to swift and going through a Tutorial on integrating AWS tools and I keep getting this error, "  No such module 'AWSCore'  "
However, on the left, you can see these modules are downloaded and there in the pod File. 
My question is how to get rid of these errors and correctly import those features. Any help on how to fix this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: After you opened the .xcworkspace file of your application, can you do a build in xcode? the build should get the artifacts and you should no longer see this error. Are you using use_frameworks! option in the Podfile?

Comment: Yes, i am using use_fameworks!, but no i can't do a build. Its still saying there is an error with the AWScore module

Answer (score 0):

1. re-create a new 'Podfile' on the Root folder of your Xcode project by running the command:

```
$ pod init
```

2. Now make sure your 'Podfile' contains the AWSCore module like shown below.

---

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target :'MyNotes' do
  use_frameworks!

    # Analytics dependency
    pod 'AWSPinpoint', '~> 2.6.10'
    pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.6.10'

    # other pods
end
```

---

Kindly note for every module you import in your project you will need to include it in your 'Podfile' and then update the 'Podfile' by running the command :

```
$ pod install
```

or

```
$ pod install --repo-update
```

3. Close the Xcode project and then open the `*.xcworkspace` file to relaunch Xcode

Comment: Always close the Xcode project / workspace before running `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this issue by adding $(BUILD_PRODUCT_DIR) ------ recursive.  I added it to me release settings as well.

[image: Build setting]

Answer (score 0):

Do not open `PROJ.xcodeproj` but rather open `PROJ.xcworkspace` in some case to build pods.

In your case, other answer should lead to right way.